# how to trace code in .net runtime

Tags: .net, trace

I want to do Performance Monitoring in my project,and i didn't want to add trace code in every function.

I want to do like(auto trace):

```
  public class ManagerBase
    {
        public void Trace()
        { 
            //trace begin
            DoSth();
            //trace end
            //i want get stacktrace in Manager.DoSth and every method's execution time
        }

        protected virtual void DoSth(){}
    }

    public class Manager : ManagerBase
    {
        protected override void DoSth()
        {
            Function1();
            Function2();
            Function3();
        }

        private void Function1() { }
        private void Function2() { }
        private void Function3() { }
    }
```

So,how can i do,thank you!

Comment: This isn't something C# can do on its own (run specified code at the start and end of a method w/o manually writing those lines of code) unless you use re-compiler/weaver, AKA aspect oriented programming. That is normally done with 3rd party tools.  You can get the boiler plate down to 1 line of code & 2 backets if you wrap the method body in a using statement where the relevant code runs in a constructor and in the dispose statement.

Comment: thank you  MatthewMartin,does 3rd party tools like "dottrace" use hook or something?